# MAC ID Binding to IP on Windows

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, mac, mac-address, windows

Is there a way i can bind a certain IP to have traffic allowed if it has a certain MAC ID on windows routing and remote access or network policies?

Basically Associated MAC ID to IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and if any other MAC ID shows it wont allow traffic?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a static entry in the RRAS's ARP table, you won't be able to communicate with any devices with that IP and a **different** MAC address.

Example from a cmd window:

> arp -s 157.55.85.212   00-aa-00-62-c6-09

Any communication with 157.55.85.212 will only work when its MAC address is 00-aa-00-62-c6-09